# Export network topology from c# in gns3

Tags: c#, networking

I have to make a program for my college that tries to determine the cost of a network by getting the length of the cables, the cost of the routers and switches associated with that network. So far, I managed to make some steps for this objective, so I can put some routers and switches, cable them and get the length of the cables, but my teacher asks me if I can export these things from C# to GNS3, so that in GNS3 I can put the configurations for the devices.

So my question is: Is there a way to send from C# information of how many routers and switches I have created(and possibly the cables that are associated with the devices) to a file that is recognized by GNS3? My teacher said that there is a way to export these through an XML file but I don't know what to write in that file or even if it's really possible.

Answer (score 1):

I did it, it was very simple actually. Its a file that GNS3 creates named topology.net and some .cfg files that can be opened with notepad. Sorry for this unworthy question.